# Connections are open with MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next-connect

I am developing a project with **NextJS** and store my data with **MongoDB** and have issues with MongoDB connections.

The connection logic is simple:

1. User connects to a page
2. Page contacts my API to get page info
3. My API using middleware gets data from MongoDB

According to the logic, I have only one user connects to mongoDB (system user). But the problem is I have a lot of connections open in MongoDB (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrO43.png)). It seems my middleware doesn't close the connection. Is this a problem with my code or it's MongoDB logic?

P.S. When I shut down my local project MongoDB connections count drops to 0.

Here is a sample of my middleware where the system connects MongoDB.

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.mongoApiUrl, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function database(req, res, next) {
  if (!client.isConnected()) await client.connect();
  req.dbClient = client;
  req.db = client.db('test');
  return next();
}

const middleware = nextConnect();

middleware.use(database);

export default middleware;
```

According to my code, If we have an open connection - to use open connection. I took the code above from this [mongodb tutorial](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nextjs-building-modern-applications/)

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that API routes are `serverless` meaning that they are created when needed and destroyed when the underlying serverless hosting structure deems appropriate. So you need to find a way **not to create** a connection to a database for every request.

```js
/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections from growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */

let cached = global.mongo

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }

    cached.promise = MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((client) => {
      return {
        client,
        db: client.db(MONGODB_DB),
      }
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}
```

You can see the complete example in the [Next.js examples repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/README.md)

Comment: Yes, this is correct logic you provided. But the major problem I am using nextConnect and .handler(), so I dont like to add for each page "await connectToDatabase()". I will try to find the solution with nextConnect()

Answer (score 0):

Here I reworked my middleware to use the cached connections. (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361191/14872716))

```
  import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
  import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

  const mongoClient = new MongoClient(process.env.mongoApiUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  //with serverless we need to use cache to prevent re-opening connection
  let cached = global.mongo


  if (!cached) {
    cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
  }

  async function database(req, res, next) {
    if (!cached.promise) {
      cached.promise = mongoClient.connect().then((client) => {
        return {
          client,
          db: client.db(process.env.MONGODB_DB),
        }
      })
      cached.conn = await cached.promise
    }

    req.dbClient = cached.conn.client
    req.db = cached.conn.db

    return next();
  }

  const middleware = nextConnect();

  middleware.use(database);


  export default middleware;
```

Answer (score 0):

given new changes on next-connect, this is how I made it worked based on previous code

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import nc from 'next-connect';

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const MONGODB_DB = process.env.MONGODB_DB

const mongoClient = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

//with serverless we need to use cache to prevent re-opening connection
let cached = global.mongo


if (!cached) {
    cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function database(req, res, next) {
    if (!cached.promise) {
        cached.promise = mongoClient.connect().then((client) => {
            return {
                client,
                db: client.db(MONGODB_DB),
            }
        })
        cached.conn = await cached.promise
    }

    req.dbClient = cached.conn.client
    req.db = cached.conn.db

    return next();
}

const middleware = nc();

middleware.use(database);


export default middleware;
```

and my .env file :

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/
MONGODB_DB=hotelcrud
```